# How to return a match and no match in two 2d list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have two 2d list with over 200 rows. I would like to find match in df1 and df2 in each sub-list and return non-matching and matching values only if the values match in df1,df2.

Here a short example

```
 df1 = [[1, 7, 3, 5], [5, 5, 14, 10]]

 df2 = [[1, 17, 3, 5], [34, 14, 74], [34, 3, 87], [25, 14, 10]]
```

Desire Result

```
 no_match = [[17],[34,87],[34,74],[25]]

 match = [[1,3,5],[3],[14],[14,10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply flatten and remove duplicates from `df1` and then iterate over `df2` using set operations to determine the difference.

```py
"""
    dataframe - a 2d list of items
    compare   - a 1d, 2d or mixed list|tuple of items to match
    log       - True/False print data
    
    returns:
        overlap    - dataframe clone with items NOT present in compare removed
        difference - dataframe clone with items present in compare removed
""" 
def convolution(dataframe:list|tuple, compare:list|tuple, log:bool=False) -> tuple:
    # init containers
    overlap, difference = [], []
    
    # flatten comparison data
    comp = []
    choice = comp.append, comp.extend
    for item in compare:
        choice[isinstance(item, list|tuple)](item)
        
    # keep only unique comparison items
    s1 = set(comp) 
    
    for sublist in dataframe:
        # cast to set
        s2 = set(sublist)

        # use set operations to compare entire sublist
        overlap.append(list(s2 & s1))
        difference.append(list(s2 - s1))
        
    if log:
        print('match: '   , overlap)
        print('no match: ', difference)
        
    return overlap, difference
```

###### usage

```py
# so you can turn on/off logging for every convolution call
VERBOSE = True 

# data
df1 = [[1, 7, 3, 5], [5, 5, 14, 10]]
df2 = [[1, 17, 3, 5], [34, 14, 74], [34, 3, 87], [25, 14, 10]]

# usage
match, no_match = convolution(df2, df1, VERBOSE)
```

###### results

```
match: [[1, 3, 5], [14], [3], [14, 10]]
no match: [[17], [34, 74], [34, 87], [25]]
```

Comment: Can it be done with flatten the list?

Comment: @Chris - if you mean `df2`, no. Flattening `df2` would scramble it and we would lose all the info on which sublist an item appeared in.

Comment: I mean do you have to flatten df1 to get it to work. Can it be done without it.

Comment: @Chris - you don't have to flatten `df1`, but not flattening it makes the code very inefficient. You seem to want to know if an item from `df2` is present anywhere in `df1`. If that's the case, flattening and removing duplicates from `df1` will allow you to check much faster, than looping over every item of every sublist of `df1` on every iteration of every item of every sublist of `df2`. My version is designed to get to the answers as fast as possible, not do the same thing over and over 1000 times.

Comment: Ok well your solution was still helpful. thank you

Comment: I was under the impression. Didn't see the update until now. Going to probably update my question or new question because I think I confused myself.